# express body parser is changing date field in body of post request

Tags: javascript, express, timezone, body-parser

When sending date field in post request in local time zone from client side is received by body parser then the body parser changes the date

left side client payload and right side what parsed on server side:

[image]

My guess is its has some thing to do with express time zone but I don't know how

I tried to set time zone of node js by setting `process.env.TZ` but the result is same

Comment: Your client-side `Date` instances are just being serialised to ISO 8601 format when they're sent in a JSON request payload. You can parse them back to `Date` instances using `new Date(req.body.date)` and then format them any way you want. **There is no problem here**

Comment: @Phil have you tried it? I'm using express v4 and its internal body parser as middleware that middleware is parsing my date object and changing the date from 22(from client side) to 21 after parsing as you can see in the image attached.
so how are you suggesting me to do `new Date(req.body.date)` with a date that is already changed by express body-parser.

Comment: Do you know that the Z at the end of String means UTC hour.?

Comment: On the client side, try logging your payload object with `console.log(JSON.stringify(payload))` and you'll see that it's sending the same date that you're receiving in Express

Comment: @Phil this point of yours make sense so when data is sent from client side date is getting changed due to stringify this means we can not use raw date object in payload so I tried by converting date to local string and then all works fine thanks

Comment: Again, it's not being _changed_ at all, just formatted differently. The ISO 8601 string is just in UTC

Answer (score -2):

So the problem was not on the backend it was on the frontend `JSON.stringify` was the problem it was changing the date so rather then sending the raw date object I'm converting date in to local String and sending that and this is working fine